# How do I change the journal path for MSMQ on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, msmq

I'm running a MSMQ 5.0 instance on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 that uses positive source journaling. My goal is to set the MSMQ journal path to its own dedicated folder on a new partition.

So far I have successfully followed the guide below - which explains how to set a new path for the message files folder, transaction logger folder and message log folder:
[Changing the MSMQ Storage location](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/02/09/changing-the-msmq-storage-location.aspx)

To summarise the steps I performed:

1. Navigated to Storage tab, in Computer Management, Services and Applications, Message Queuing properties.
2. Set the new paths under the appropriate headings for Message files folder, Message logger folder and Transaction logger folder
3. Clicked Apply

The problem is that the journal appears to be stored in the same location as the message files folder; whereas I want the journal in a dedicated folder on a new partition. I can't see any option to do this.

I also tried changing the *StoreJournalPath* registry value on a test server under *HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters* to the value for the new path. I couldn't see a build up of files for the new path after restarting the test server and sending several messages to the journal.

Has anyone managed to do this before?